# Maven building successfully without actually downloading dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

I am a beginner to Maven and using build tools like it in general. I am running Maven `mvn` in the terminal to understand how it works better. I found [this FFT library](https://github.com/tambapps/fourier-transform-library), git-cloned it, found a pom.xml inside it and ran

```
mvn package
```

The build completed and a `target/` directory was created with the JAR file for the library inside. However, I inspected the POM file and found that there were  dependencies for `junit`, which are needed for running tests written in `src/test/` but there were no JAR files created in target/ for junit (and I needed to download them separately from MVN repository and place them in target/). So my question is how does Maven actually build the JAR file without also pulling the JAR file(s) for junit? My current understanding is that it parses the POM file and goes through each dependency and downloads and installs them if they isn't present (like Make i guess?).

Comment: Maven downloads them in globally shared `repository` in `~/.m2` (the maven home directory). So if you have build other projects with maven before junit probably will be there without the need to download it. It will not download nor copy things (unless explicitly configured to do so) to the `target` directory.

Comment: If you need to download something manually you are doing something wrong... If you need for example junit you have to define a dependency with scope: test... Maven will download it automatically etc. and no the jar's will not being put into `target` directory. The target directory only contains your own code which is being compiled from `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven downloads and keeps the dependencies in the local Maven repository that can be found in `~/.m2/repository`. This is done so that builds can share the dependencies, and so that they don't get lost if you run `mvn clean`.

Comment: Thanks that definitely makes a lot of sense. So if I need to provide the classpath i'll just add `"~/.m2/repository/*"` to the `-cp` when compiling with `javac` or running with `java`? Is that whats normally done?

Comment: When running with `java` no, include only those jars you (or better use maven to run it), to run `javac` no you have maven and you don't need to call `javac`.